# Bad array new length error in OpenCV program

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to get feed from webcam and store in a folder using VideoWriter but after running the code in visual it popped this error saying bad array new length. The execution is not passing the (isWriterOpened) statement.The program is made in visual studio -> debug mode -> window console application (x64).

```
 //create matrix to store image
Mat image;

//initialize the camera
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Cant get the feed from camera.";
    return -1;
}

//filename string
std::string filename = "C:/Users/Guru/Videos/OpenCV_Feed/myVideo.avi";

//fourcc integer
int fcc = VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');

//frames size
cv::Size frameSize((int)cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int)cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

//frame per second
int fps = 20;


VideoWriter writer("outcpp.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, frameSize);

if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Writer is not opened";
    getchar();

    return -1;

}
```

Error I got
: [ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_MSMF(filename, fourcc, fps, framesize, isColor)): raised C++ exception: bad array new length